# Changing file type for multiple files at once using awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to change .dat files to .csv files using the awk command. An example file has 3 columns of numbers with spaces between each column:

```
23.00005 320.0054 0.0039734                                              
xx.xxxxx xxx.xxxx x.xxxxxxx
```

The filenames are organized as `filenameX.project.dat` where `X` is any number from 1 to a couple hundred. The folder has many other files that I do not want changed. I want to be able to change all of these files at once instead of having to do them over and over.

Here is my example command:

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3}' filenameX.project.dat > filenameX.project.csv
```

How can I automate this to run one command that will make every file a csv file?
I have tried the below command and others similar but none work.

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3}' filename*.project.dat > filename*.project.csv
```

Comment: Huh? What have the contents of the files got to do with changing their filename extensions? Does what is in the file have any relevance to what needs doing to the file's name?

Comment: I specified the contents because it explains the need for '{print $1","$2","3}' since csv files are recognized be separating the columns with commas.

Comment: You don't want to change the file contents at all though do you? You just want to change the extension.

Comment: Well I need to separate the columns by commas in order to be able to read the file in another program later. But my issue is solely in the changing of the extension so it may be possible that I did't need to include the rest of the question but I figured it couldn't hurt to give the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$ for i in filename*dat; do awk '{print $1","$2","$3}' "$i" >> $(echo "$i" | sed 's,\.dat$,.csv,'); done
```

It will loop through all `filename*dat` files in a directory, execute `awk` command on them and redirect output to the file that has `.csv` instead of `.dat` at the end.

Comment: This gives me the output "bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'".

Comment: Remove the initial `$`, I put it here as a prompt. Other popular characters for this purpose are `#`, `>` and others.

Comment: Of course! that makes sense. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in `awk` like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} 
     FNR==1 {fn=FILENAME; sub(/\.dat$/,".csv",fn)
             printf "Copying %s to %s\n", FILENAME, fn}  
     { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, i<NF ? OFS : RS > fn}' *.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make a backup first, as I am still not certain what you mean, but suspect it is:

```
rename -n -S .dat .csv filename*.project.dat
```

If it looks good, remove the `-n` and run again for real.